# How to fix, My input HTML5 pattern dosn't match pattern correctly

Tags: html, regex, pattern-matching

I need do a regex that can validate the next points:

1. 1111111 -> Is incorrect
2. 1111222 -> Is correct
3. 1234111 -> Is correct
4. 1234511 -> Is incorrect
5. 2011111 -> Is incorrect
6. 2001111 -> Is correct
7. 2012345 -> Is incorrect

I cant do more of 5 numbers in a row example:11111,2011111,1111120 and i cant do more of 5 consecutive numbers in a row, example:1234520, 2012345.

i already make the regex but when i put this into pattern input html5, this doesn'nt work

What am i doing bad??

What other thing i need?

Link regex: https://regex101.com/r/GapcVI/1

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
Telephone: <input type="tel" name="phone" pattern="(?!(?:(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){4,}\d)|(?!^(.(?!([0-9]\1{2,})))*$)|(?!^(.(?!((?:(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){4,}\d))))*$))\d*" maxlength="7" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I do test into regex101, this work fine!!. But when i go to pattern HTML5, does'nt work.

By some reason only can submit the form putting 1 digit into input, is very strange

Comment: Doesn't have to be that complicated `^(?!.*(\d)\1{4})(?:0(?!1234)|1(?!2345)|2(?!3456)|3(?!4567)|4(?!5678)|5(?!6789)|[6-9])+$`

Comment: It may need to have the escapes escaped as in `"\\d"` Anyway, if you need a simpler way to do it - https://regex101.com/r/JIrMBF/1

Comment: Why do you need to test these stupid conditions? If someone enters a wrong number, this isn't your problem.